# How can I get Form Validation to work when using a "shared" button (instead of an input element of type "submit")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, meteor

I've got some validation ("required") in my HTML like so:

```
<input class="firstblockinput" type="text" id="travelername" title="Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial" required />
```

The page has a "shared" button on it:

```
<template name="postTravelWizard">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getStepTemplate}}
    <!-- <button type="button" name="nextStep"  
id="nextStep">Next</button> -->
    <input type="submit" name="nextStep" id="nextStep" value="Submit">
</template>
```

This button is "constant" to all the Templates (which are dynamically swapped out). The button works fine as far as replacaing one Template with another with this code:

```
Template.postTravelWizard.events({
  'click #nextStep': function(e, t) {
     var step = Session.get('stepNum');
     step = (step) < 5 ? ++step : 1;
     Session.set('stepNum', step);

     if ($('#visitor').is(':checked')) {
       console.log('visitor is checked');
       var visaselection = $('select[name="selvisatype"]').val();
       console.log('visaselection is ' + visaselection);
  }
},
```

However, the form validation does not fire, presumably because this is a button, and not an input of type "submit".

But if I change it from a button to an input type="submit", that is to say from this:

```
<button type="button" name="nextStep" id="nextStep">Next</button>
```

...to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="nextStep" id="nextStep" value="Next">
```

..and the event handler to this:

```
Template.postTravelWizard.events({
//'click #nextStep': function(e, t) {
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //save something...
    var step = Session.get('stepNum');
    step = (step) < 5 ? ++step : 1;
    Session.set('stepNum', step);

    if ($('#visitor').is(':checked')) {
      console.log('visitor is checked');
      var visaselection = $('select[name="selvisatype"]').val();
      console.log('visaselection is ' + visaselection);
      // When this is working (the first two return "visaselection is undefined" and the last one returns simply
      // "visaselection is "), do something similar for ucemployee (input type=radio) and selectcampus (select element)
    }
},
```

...it won't swap out the Templates. In fact, the breakpoint I set in the "'submit form': function(e) {" handler (on the "e.preventDefault();" line) is not even reached...???

It's a "Catch-22" situation.

Do I have to, in a case such as this, manually validate the form entries?

Comment: Could submit events only being fired in HTML5 if all form elements with validation attributes are valid be the issue? That is, iff any element fails validation, no submit event is generated

Comment: But they should display their gripes if anything is failing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox at least a submit action is required before the browser will generated error messages. For reasoning, say, it's not an error to not have yet filled in a required field, it's only an error to try submitting the form in that state.

So,

> presumably because this is a button, and not an input of type "submit"

would be correct. As per comment, HTML5 blocks submission if any form element fails validatation. Hence the modified event handler, registered for **submit** events, never gets called if the form contains errors. Hence the breakpoint set is never reached, as you observe. *Having said that I would expect errors to be displayed when a submit button is pressed - please advise details if not*.

Hence for the #nextStop button to generate **browser error messages** for a form on screen, it really needs to be a submit button. (Naturally it can still have mouse event handlers, and if form submission is to be prevented, a submit event listener can cancel the action).

Noting CSS validation pseudo classes :invalid, :valid, :required may give users early warning of problem entries.